# How to password protect a static website? (without htaccess)

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have a static website that I want to protect with a username and/or password like apache's htaccess does but I don't want to host an apache server for it to work. How can I achieve this without frontend javascript?

The closest I've come using frontend JS (too insecure because source is visible):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script>
  var password = "password";
  (function promptPass() {
    var psw = prompt("Enter your Password");
    while (psw !== password) {
      alert("Incorrect Password");
      return promptPass();
    }
  }());
  alert('Correct Password\nWelcome!');
</script>

<body align="center">
  <h1>Password Protected Site</h1>
  <!-- Other page elements -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything you do on the front end can be bypassed by the user. Security must be implemented on the server.

Comment: "*I don't want to host an apache server for it to work*" - why not? And there are alternatives to Apache. What are you currently using to host the web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default security has to be done on the backend (as already stated by others).

But one thing came to my mind to do some security on the frontend:

Use some JavaScript to request a passwort from the user and use this password for decrypting some encrypted string already available within the delivered page and replace the `body`'s content with the decrypted data. There should be some libraries available for encrypting/decrypting data using JavaScript.

Comment: I was afraid I would have to use a server, I appreciate the explanation of why and it does make sense that it would have to be backend. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: While this will work, be aware of the risks. In short this would be quite weak against a committed and resourceful attacker. The direct concern with this proposed solution is that the password should not be used directly to encrypt the data, a proper key derivation function should instead be used to derive a key from the password. The attacker in this setup could use all the time and resources to crack this really efficiently offline. This further emphasizes the need for a KDF to slow that down somewhat. Also user passwords are usually easy to guess.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, anything that goes to frontend will always be visible. so to password protect a static html page you should password protect the file itself or you should prompt for a password from the page where this page is redirected.

Answer (score 1):

I think technically you can get away without a server for security.  Proof-of-concept thought experiment... if the entire HTML content of the page was readable but encrypted, and say a user had to type the decryption key into a popup, then in theory client-side JavaScript could decrypt the page content, without being circumventable.

Only issue is it would be the same password for every user, unless there is something clever you can do about that..

Answer (score 0):

If I had to come up with something under these conditions, I'd be thinking of something along the lines of hashing the username and password and using that as the url for a file on the server that contains the actual content of the page and then using JS to load that in.

But still, doing the security on the backend is a much better option if you actually care about security and not about just making it challenging for most users.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you will at least require a little JS since HTML simply doesn't have any logic constructs to accomplish what you need. If you REALLY want to keep it static, I would go about it by using a strong JS obfuscator, such as [Obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/).